# Posts on user feed with wrong content after group similar posts

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

My app has a button which starts Facebook web dialog. After login, the app has a dialog to user write some content, and when he clicks on button 'Share' we post a link on his behalf.

Doing the 'Share' action 2 or 3 times, in a short time, the Facebook groups similar contents on User Feed and, instead of it shows normal content, it shows something like what is shown on the picture attached. User Timeline is normal.

We're using the following implemetation to post a link:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("name", getString(R.string.app_name));
postParams.putString("caption", getResources().getString(R.string.home));
postParams.putString("description", someDescription);
postParams.putString("message", someMessage);
postParams.putString("picture", a link to a picture);
postParams.putString("link", a link to open the page to download the app);


final Request request = new Request(this.session,
"me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST);

request.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(final Response response) {
final FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();

  if (error == null) {
   // Do something
  } else {
   switch (error.getErrorCode()) {
    case FEED_LIMIT:
     // Do something
    break;

    case DUPLICATE_MESSAGE:
     // Do something
    break;

    case MISSING_MESSAGE:
    // Do something
    break;

    case CONNECTION:
     // Do something
     break;

    default:
    // Do something
    break;
  }
}});


request.executeAsync();
```

[image: My feed, after share same content in a short time.]

We just do that, and we can reproduce and see it happening.

Hope it helps to understand.

Comment: If you are clicking only once then everything is working fine..

Comment: Yes, only once works normally. But if appears more than one of the same content, on my feed, or friend's, it will be that way.

Comment: I think its an issue of thread synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but I think that its an issue of synchronization. Better you try your code using synchronization when you are posting link on behalf of user or what you can do is you can maintain a flag to check whether your previous request is completed before sending a new request.

Method 1: using synchronized keyword.

```
void post_request () {
    synchronized (request) {
        //post your link here and wait for your request completion.
    }
}
```

Method 2: Maintain a flag.

```
boolean is_request_in_process = false;

void post_request () {
      if (!is_request_in_process) {
           is_request_in_process = true;
           // post your request here and wait for confirmation.
           // after completion is_request_in_process = false;
      }
}
```

You can also combine both method and check:

```
Request request_obj = null;
boolean is_request_in_process = false;

    void post_request () {
        synchronized (request_obj) {
              if (!is_request_in_process) {
                   is_request_in_process = true;
                   // post your request here and wait for confirmation.
                   // after completion is_request_in_process = false;
              }
           }
        }
```

I am not sure but hope it can help you.

Comment: I dont have eclipse in my personal laptop so code I have written is just for an example. I am not sure but I have messed several times with similar issues in which we post event to servers and before completion of first request if we post same again then exception comes I think reason is you are using common resources for the two different processes at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), but do you think that could be something like this? Because I think it's strange posts getting this way. I also noticed that if some friend of mine share a similar content while I share too, it will be the same way. I was wondering if can be something with API or something.

Comment: Looking to your example, I understand that I'll give a delay to post again, but I believe that Facebook's feed will continue to group contents because they're similar. What do you think?

Comment: I noticed that my link loses part of its information after posts get grouped, and so, the resulting link opens a page with an error. The title of this page is the same that appears on post, after group. Could this help to understand what is happening?

Comment: Now think that you are calling a function X() in which your link you are posting or other side where you are posting, a method is present X() and your link is stored in a member variable URL. Function X () takes 500 milisecond to process and return. Now if you call function X () two times within 500 milisecond URL will be change between processing of function X (). In this case, It may override it with some other value or may be when you posts it is converting into some other form to process but in between you will call you function and override it.

Comment: According to your problem I analyzed that this is happening when same resource is accessed or written multiple times simultaneously. If some other problem is there then is should happen in normal cases also. have you tried above solution ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with synchronized option, but, even with it, if you post same contents, in short time, same happens. I'll try waiting longer and see if still happens the same.

Comment: If you remove some of the contents and leave just one, it backs to normal. Weird, isn't it?

Comment: Even waiting longer to post again, the posts gets this way. I think it's because the content, that is similar to previous one. I reported it to Facebook, and I'm waiting feedback.

Comment: I found a tool, indicated by Facebook called Object Debugger that inspects the link you're trying to show. I figure out that my link had a problem in one of the params and that's why it was getting wrong. Recently, the link get back to normal and the posts as well. Thanks you all for the help :)